# Vue.js how to change app data from component

Tags: vue.js, events

I have a form component which should add new data to the root Vue aplication instance.
Component form looks like

```
Vue.component('new-item-form', {
    template:   '<form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">' +
                    '<input v-model="newCategoryName" type="text" value="">' +
                    '<input type="submit" value="Add new item">' +
                '</form>',
    props: [

    ],
    data: function () {
        return {
            newCategoryName: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formSubmit: function()
        {
            alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
            this.$emit('addItemEvent', this.newCategoryName);
        }
    }
});
```

and here is aplication code

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        dude: 'Jack Frost',
        vueAppCategories: [
            {foreach $categories as $c}
                {* Vytvorý js objekt *}
                {   title: {$c->title}, status: {$c->status}, priority: {$c->priority}  }
                {sep}, {/sep}
            {/foreach}
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        'addItem': function($event) {
            alert('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb');
            this.vueAppCategories.unshift({ title: $event, status: 55, priority: 100 });
        }
    }
});
```

formSubmit method works fine and show alert. But I dont know how to hook addItemEvent on the root Vue aplication which should modify root data. How to hook addItemEvent on aplication? Thanks.

Comment: please share the app.vue or the main.js

Comment: plus how your using it and where. `this.$emit` fires the event back to the parent/caller like when used `<new-item-form @addItemEvent="someMethod"/>`. besides what root Vue application and what data do you want to change?

Comment: There it is. I want to change data.vueAppCategories. It should call addItem method. Root means app = new Vue();

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in camel case. The event name should be in snake-case format.

```
<new-item-form @add-item-event="parentAddItem"></new-item-form>
```

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/emit-event-does-not-trigger-parent-action/101031